# When to use Tableau or Einstein Analytics for Advanced reporting

Tags: reporting, einstein-analytics, analytics, tableau

When [Salesforce native Reports, Charts and Dashboards](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/reports_dashboards/reports_dashboards_overview) are not enough and you needed advanced functionality like:

- Dynamic discovery of data instead of pure display
- integrate external data sources
- Overcome record and data format restrictions
- allow for more interactivity with the data
- do advanced calculations that can not be done with Custom Objects and custom fields
- (many others) ...

the recommended solution was to use [Einstein Analytics](https://www.salesforce.com/eu/products/einstein-analytics/overview/).

Now with the [recent acquisition of Tableau](https://investor.salesforce.com/press-releases/press-release-details/2019/Salesforce-Signs-Definitive-Agreement-to-Acquire-Tableau/default.aspx#:%7E:text=As%20part%20of%20Salesforce%2C%20Tableau,its%20mission%2C%20customers%20and%20community.) by Salesforce, I am confused when and why to choose what.

1. How do both tools compare?
2. Will they eventually be merged or discontinued?
3. When do I definitely choose the one over the other?
4. What should I do when I heavily invested in Einstein Analytics?
5. Is there a preference when it comes to Managed packages? Can ISV package both technologies?
6. What else should be asked and answered in this context?

Comment: As per my understanding tableau is more famous in on-premise tech, so packaging would be difficult/not possible.

Comment: This is a good question, and I would love to hear opinions about this. I'm also confused since the 2 products seem to tackle the same problem. I do personally believe that Tableau will replace Einstein Analytics in the long run.